# How to change the checkbox into label in gridview binding

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i already bind database in gridview in that table having 0's and 1's that is boolean (true or false) in 2nd and 3rd column. when i get the output browser will showing disabled checkbox if true checked disabled checkbox show otherwise disable checkbox showing. my question is if checked checkbox replace some image unchecked checkbox replace some image in c#

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvedition" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
CssClass="table table-responsive" OnRowDataBound="gvedition_RowDataBound">
</asp:Gridview>
```

in c#

```
 protected void bindedition()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_edition_comparison", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            gvedition.DataSource = dt;
            gvedition.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

in sql table

```
sno  feature                        starter    standard
1     master                            1         1
2     process menu                      1         1
3     master report                     0         1
4     audit report                      0         1
```

[but view in browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8D9o.jpg)

Comment: You need to read about template column of GridView.

Comment: how??? this gridview i'm creating in run time

Comment: Set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` or remove this line.

Comment: That's what you need to read about @JeenathKumar

Comment: sorry.... i don't know how to do this. can you please show in code. what will change from this. did you see the image. how to replace that checkbox into some html element like "<i class="fas fa-check"></i>" Thank you...... @Chetan Ranpariya